# How do i use dependency injection correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, ninject

So, this is my first time using Ninject, everything worked great, until i ran into a problem where Some service classes needed addition ModelState argument in constructor. Problem was solved by answer on this question : [answer on previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141166/how-to-inject-modelstate-as-parameter-with-ninject)

Now next problem were that i have about 40 service classes which need to have access to ModelState in constructor, therefor i choose to use generics, and i really don't know if this is actually legit in any way? or do i have to redo it?

```
private readonly IServiceFactory<IAccountService, AccountService> service;
public AccountController(IServiceFactory<IAccountService, AccountService> asf)
{           
  this.service = asf;
}
```

RegisterServices from Ninject:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind(typeof(IServiceFactory<,>)).To(typeof(ServiceFactory<,>));
}
```

Generics:

```
public interface IServiceFactory<T, Y> where T : class  where Y : class
{
     T Create(ModelStateDictionary modelState);
}

public class ServiceFactory<T, Y> : IServiceFactory<T, Y>
    where T : class
    where Y : class
{

    public T Create(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        var x = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (Y), new ModelStateWrapper(modelState));
        return x;
    }
}
```

What i tryed to achieve, is that i wanted to avoid creating 40 factory interfaces and 40 factorys to make exatcly the same thing. My solution works, but does it actually support Dependency Injection? i cant really figure it out.

Comment: when i read your question i feel that you are going in the wrong way... i think what you are really need is [Ambient context](https://aabs.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/the-ambient-context-design-pattern-in-net/). and then you won't need 40 factories.

Comment: The problem is that Services wants to have ModelState inside the constructor, because person who worked on the solution before me, choose to make validation in Service layer. So when i want to Inject Account service then i need to find a way to pass ModelState of current view together with the service.

Comment: @Timsen - no, your problem is that ModelState doesn't exist until after the controller is fully constructed.  Thus, you can't inject ModelState from the constructor of the controller, it can only be done afterwards in some other method like the article you linked to does by passing it to a factory to create after the controller is fully constructed.  But that's beside the point, I don't understand why you feel you need to create 40 different factories

Comment: One for each service where ModelState is needed? or have i completly misunderstood something?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch or u just want to suggest to have a separate method on the services which just load ModelState when its needed?

Comment: If you note the last part of [my answer on your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141166/how-to-inject-modelstate-as-parameter-with-ninject#29145573) there is another option to pass the ModelState directly to the `IAccountService` rather than creating a factory, which be the right solution in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you note the last part of [my answer on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141166/how-to-inject-modelstate-as-parameter-with-ninject#29145573), you can also just pass the reference to ModelState directly through the `IAccountService` interface. In this case, that would simplify things, but given the lack of context in your previous question it was unclear which would be the better choice.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILanguageService languageService;
    private readonly ISessionHelper sessionHelper;
    private readonly IAccountService accountService;

    public AccountController(ILanguageService languageService, ISessionHelper sessionHelper, IAccountService accountService)
    {
        if (languageService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("languageService");
        if (sessionHelper == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sessionHelper");
        if (accountService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("accountService");

        this.languageService = languageService;
        this.sessionHelper = sessionHelper;
        this.accountService = sessionHelper;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostSomething()
    {

        // Pass model state of the current request to the service.
        this.accountService.DoSomething(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState));

    }
}
```

This is clearly easier than injecting 40 factories, and would make your DI configuration simpler.

The only downside of this approach (if you can call it that) is that your `IAccountService` interface now requires an implemenatation of `IValidationDictionary` to be passed. This means that every concrete implementation of `IAccountService` must have a dependency on ModelState's abstraction, `IValidationDictionary`. If that is the expectation of the design, then that is fine.

Also, you should put guard clauses in your class to ensure that if the DI container fails to provide an instance an exception will be thrown. The `readonly` keyword in the private fields makes it impossible to change the value of those fields outside of the constructor. Basically, these 2 things combined guarantee that you will have an instance that is initialized in the constructor and will remain constant throughout the lifetime of the object.

**Final Thoughts**

DI is by its nature complex. If you want to get a good answer, you should provide more context about the problem. I realize that SO says that you should post the minimum required code, but questions about DI generally require more context to answer than other questions because of its complexity.

Had I known you were trying to solve a problem for 40 similar services or had known about the relevant part of the `IAccountService` members that use the dependency (which you still haven't provided), my answer probably would have been different. It could still change if you provide more context, but there are only so many assumptions I can make about what you are trying to achieve. It helps a lot if you fill in the blanks.

Comment: I agree with you (+1). Questions about DI are generally are often hard to answer without context because it often tends to be a discussion about applying design patterns correctly (which is the beauty of DI IMO), which is very context specific.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection is mapping a **concrete** implementation to an **abstract/interface** and pass that instance on the constructor of the dependant class.

Mapping:

```
kernel.Bind<IServiceAccount>().To<ServiceAccount>();
```

Depentandt class:

```
private readonly IServiceAccount _serviceAccount;
public AccountController(IServiceAccount serviceAccount)
{
 _serviceAccount = serviceAccount;
}
```

In your case it seems you should rethink the way your service work unless you wan't to create a factory for each service you use, do you need the modelstate on the constructor?, maybe you could change it to a method inside your service when you use it, if your workflow doesn't allow for a invalid state throw an exception.

In case you need to use a runtime value for creating an instance of your service  you need to create a factory for it.

```
public class ValidServiceAccount : IServiceAccount
{}

public class InvalidServiceAccount : IServiceAccount
{}

public interface IServiceAccountFactory
{
 IServiceAccount Create(bool modelState);
}

public class ServiceAccountFactory : IServiceAccountFactory
{
 public IServiceAccount Create(bool modelState)
 {
  return modelState ? new ValidServiceAccount() : new InvalidServiceAccount();
 }
}
```

And instead of passing an IServiceAccount on yoru controller constructor you pass a IServiceAccountFactory, you can see this can easily add a lot of complexity to your project but when you really need the flexibility it really pays off.

Note: on asp.net MVC projects you should get the ninject controller factory so it take care of the constructors for you (i think the package is called Ninject.MVC).