# How to register generic with two types in Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, generics, simple-injector

Here is my Interface and class :

```
 public interface IServiceFactory<T, Y> where T : class  where Y : class
{
     T Create(ModelStateDictionary modelState);
}

public class ServiceFactory<T, Y> : IServiceFactory<T, Y>
    where T : class
    where Y : class
{

    public T Create(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        var x = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (Y), new ModelStateWrapper(modelState));
        return x;
    }
}
```

container register of Simple Injector:

```
  container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IServiceFactory<, >), typeof(IServiceFactory<, >));
```

How to set up Simple Injector to work with generics which contain more than one type?

Comment: What problems are you having?  Failure to compile?  Exceptions at run time?  A program that runs, but with unexpected results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Register(Type, IEnumerable<Assembly>)` (`RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` in v2) allows doing batch registration. So in general you supply the `Register` with an open generic type and one or more `Assembly` instances, and the method will iterate through the types in the assemblies and will register all non-generic implementations of the suppiled generic type.

What you seem to want is to map an open-generic abstraction to an open-generic implementation in such way that when a closed-generic abstraction is requested, a closed-generic implementation is returned.

This is the way to do this:

```cs
// Simple Injector v3.x
container.Register(typeof(IServiceFactory<,>), typeof(ServiceFactory<,>));

// Simple Injector v2.x
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IServiceFactory<,>), typeof(ServiceFactory<,>));
```

btw, I've read your earlier questions and you seem to be mislead by the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141166/how-to-inject-modelstate-as-parameter-with-ninject). The answerer correctly states that `ModelState` is an runtime value and you should not inject this runtime value in the constructor of a service. The use of a factory will only move the problem, because inside the factory you are still injecting the runtime value into the constructor of the service. This breaks the dependency graph and prevents you from [verifying](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#verify-configuration) and [diagnosing](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/diagnostics.html) your object graphs.

In this case I would advice to simply pass the `ModelState` on to the service method.